# JSF get table rows data inside managed bean

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I'm new to JSF and I'm trying to get rows data inside a data table when submit button is pressed. I read about DataModel but I don't know how to use it in my case, my code is as follows:

View:

```
<p:dataTable binding="#{examSchedule.myDataTable}" 
             value="#{examSchedule.deptCourses}" 
             rowIndexVar="index" 
             id="dataTableID" 
             rendered="#{not empty examSchedule.deptCourses}"    
             var="data">

    <p:column headerText="m">
        #{index+1}
    </p:column>

    <p:column headerText="sub">
        <p:outputLabel value="#{data.name}" />
    </p:column>

    <p:column headerText="start date">
        <p:calendar id="startTime" 
                    value="#{examSchedule.startDate}" 
                    pattern="HH:mm" 
                    timeOnly="true" />
    </p:column>

    <p:column headerText="end date">
        <p:calendar id="endTime" 
                    value="#{examSchedule.endDate}" 
                    pattern="HH:mm" timeOnly="true" />                  
    </p:column>

    <f:facet name="footer">
        <p:commandButton value="save" 
                         ajax="false" 
                         type="submit" 
                         action="#{examSchedule.save}" 
                         update="dataTableID" />
    </f:facet>

</p:dataTable>
```

Model:

```
@Named(value="examSchedule")
public class ExamScheduleBean {

    private DataTable myDataTable;
    private List<Courses> DeptCourses;

    public void getTableColumns() {
        for(int i = 0; i < DeptCourses.size(); i++) {
            myDataTable.setRowIndex(i);
            List<org.primefaces.component.api.UIColumn> columns = myDataTable.getColumns();
            for (org.primefaces.component.api.UIColumn uiColumn : columns) {
                System.out.println(uiColumn.getField());                
            }
        }
    }

    public void save() {
         getTableColumns();
    }
}
```

Assuming that `DeptCourses` has data, I want to get all rows inside data table when I click the save button. I tried the code inside `getTableColumns()` but it prints `null`, i'm not able to save deptCourses because only the first column gets its data from these list and the other columns has no data for these list, the user will enter data before submitting,  any idea about how to do that?

Comment: try adding get/Set in bean to list and dataTable..just to testing.

Comment: Umm is ***for(Courses tempCourse:deptCourses){ System.out.println(tempCourse.getName()+" : "+empCourse.getStartDate()+" : "+empCourse.getEndDate();)}*** not allowed? Is component binding mandated and value binding frowned upon? Please add a scope to your CDI bean as well